# Download Website with formatting using Wget

Tags: php, batch-file, formatting, download, wget

I have a PHP script which runs on our website and echos a bunch of content to the browser, each line has a unique ID. I installed GnuWin32 and wrote a small BAT script to download this content to a TXT file which is working fine, however when viewed in Notepad it has lost the line breaks.

I have tried appending "\r\n" and "\n" to the echo string in the PHP script but still have this issue. Can anyone please point out where my mistake is?

```
@echo off
setlocal
set TARGET=website.com/report_file.php
wget -O ServerID.txt -p %TARGET%
endlocal
```

Comment: have you tried the php PHP_EOL constant?

Comment: I just gave that a try but having the same issue with that. It shows up as individual lines in Wordpad but not Notepad for some reason.

Comment: and when you do two of them? i.e.  echo "line A" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . "line B"

Comment: Same problem in Notepad, rather than each on its own line, it shows up such as "Line1Line2Line3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have  LF (`0x0a`) terminated lines in your `.txt` file. Notepad handles CRLF (`0x0d 0x0a`) terminated lines.

If you are using gnuwin32, you can use `conv` to change the line endings in your file.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about conv :)